# ultima compra de un cliente

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la tabla Sales.SalesOrderHeader de AdventureWorks2019 el codigo es:

```
select  SO.CustomerID, SO.SalesOrderID
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader as SO
order by (SO.CustomerID) asc, (SO.SalesOrderID) desc
```

Me sale cada CustomerID repetido con cada SalesOrderID que tenga y necesito mostrar solamente por cada CustomerID el SalesOrderID mas alto, serian un solo CustomerID con un solo SalesOrderID.

Comment: JLP, podrias decir si la respuesta dada te resulto util, gracias

Comment: JLP podrias marcar la respuesta como aceptada y darle tu voto si te resulto util, gracias

Answer (score 1):

```
select SO.CustomerID, max(SO.SalesOrderID)
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader as SO
group by SO.CustomerID
```

Utilizas la **cláusula group by** junto con la **función de agregación max** aplicada al **campo SalesOrderID**, de esta forma obtendrás por cada valor del **campo CustomerID**, el valor máximo correspondiente del **campo SalesOrderID**.

Comment: Gracias esta bien!

Comment: @JLP si la respuesta te resultó útil agradecería que la marcaras como aceptada y dieras un voto positivo, gracias